# Room partial update

Tags: android, android-room

I am trying to update partial fields in my Android Room database.

I am using @Update with a partial class:

```
@Update(entity = BehaviorDataSent::class)
fun update(obj: BehaviorDataSentUpdate)

@Entity(tableName = "BehaviorDataSent")  
data class BehaviorDataSent(@PrimaryKey val actionTime: Long, val netName: String? = null, val savedTime: Long = 0, val sentTime: Long? = null)

data class BehaviorDataSentUpdate(val actionTime: Long, val sentTime: Long )
```

However, I get an error saying that the update method must have a body.
What have I missed?

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that the `@Update` is in an abstract class rather than an interface. As such it needs to be an abstract function (or have a body).

so :-

```
@Update(entity = BehaviorDataSent::class)
abstract fun update(obj: BehaviorDataSentUpdate)
```

or change `abstract class ....` to `interface`

and/or you could use :-

```
@Query("UPDATE behaviordatasent SET sentTime=:sentTime WHERE actionTime=:actionTime")
abstract fun update(sentTime: Long, actionTime: Long)
```

- in which case the BehaviourDataSentUpdate class is not required.
- if in an interface then abstract should not be coded.

**i.e.** in an `interface` abstract is implied and thus does not need to be coded.However, in an abstract class functions without bodies need to be abstract and thus you can also have non-abstract functions that then need a body.